# Mouse driver needs update in Mac

Tags: macos

I have a Microsoft optical wheel mouse (several actually) which work perfect in MS Windows.

However in Mac (lastest OS Monterrey), the scroll wheel sometimes behaves eradically, by scrolling the screen up a bit while I am using mouse wheel repeatedly to scroll it down.

I connected my friend's newer Dell mouse which does not behave that way.

It's definitely a problem with the mouse driver included in OSX.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: That sounds like a standard hardware problem: the quadrature encoder acting up. Are you absolutely sure that this doesn't happen on Windows?

Comment: @gronostaj  I used the mouse for years on Windows and never noticed any such behavior as occasionally scrolling up while using wheel to scroll down.  The behavior was immediately apparent when plugging into a mac

Comment: Well, it's not impossible that the mouse started to fail around that time. Especially if it's a couple years old. It would be good to test it with Windows for a while just to be sure, because that's really a typical misbehavior of a dusty/failing encoder.

Comment: Why not just strip it & make sure the encoder's clean. It only takes one tiny hair to upset them.

Comment: How would I strip it?  The mouse doesn't seem to be able to come apart   https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31N7ENCV2ZL._AC_.jpg

Comment: If you can't see screws underneath, they will be behind the feet gliders or product sticker. If you're careful you can get them off & retain enough sticky to put them back afterwards. I still have one of those old MS mice kicking around somewhere, must be 15-20 years old, but I can't put my hand on it right now so I can't test the theory for you.